# Retrieve string date and long date from query result

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a date field defined in index as

```
"_reportDate": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis"
                }
```

and I have a query to query from _source field which gives _reportDate field in string of 2015-12-05 01:05:00.

I can't seems to find a way to get date in different date format during query retrieval apart from using script field (which is not preferable). From what I understand a date field will be parse to long value to be indexed in elastic search, can we retrieve the long value as well during elasticsearch query?

Comment: Only using a script field as you noted. But nothing prevents you from indexing another field containing the long value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the field and at search time ask for this stored field.

If it does not work you can always apply the script at index time with ingest feature and a script processor.